# Heroku installing wrong python version

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, requirements.txt

My application(discord bot - discord.py-v2) works fine locally.
I have given `python-3.10.4` in the runtime.txt file.
When I try to push the changes to Heroku, it says `Installing python-3.6.13`. There are errors during the execution of the requirements.txt file.
Another app with the same requirements.txt file and python3.10 works fine on SparkedHost.

**requirements.txt**

```
aiohttp>=3.7.4,<4
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout
attrs==21.4.0
autopep8==1.6.0
discord-ext-bot==1.0.1
discord-py-interactions==4.2.1
discord-py-slash-command==4.2.1
discord.py @ git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@1ba290d8c6884daa8a8548ab203fb12bd736576d
import-expression==1.1.4
msgpack==1.0.3
multidict==6.0.2
python-dotenv==0.20.0
python-lsp-jsonrpc==1.0.0
python-lsp-server==1.4.1
pytz==2022.2.1
requests==2.27.1
```

**Errors:**

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord-ext-bot==1.0.1 (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord-ext-bot==1.0.1
```

If I remove `discord-ext-bot==1.0.1, discord-py-interactions==4.2.1, and discord-py-slash-command` from the file, it says error in `discord.py` version

Comment: Is your `runtime.txt` in the root directory of your project? Is it UTF-8 encoded? Are you sure it's committed, and there isn't an old version? It's strange that you're getting Python 3.6 since 3.10 is the current default.

Comment: [Which stack are you using](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#viewing-which-stack-your-app-is-using)? Python 3.6 is not supported on any current stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`runtime.txt`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) and specify the python version there.

Edit: Heroku only supports certain python versions:

```
python-3.10.6 on all supported stacks (recommended)
python-3.9.13 on all supported stacks
python-3.8.13 on Heroku-18 and Heroku-20 only
python-3.7.13 on Heroku-18 and Heroku-20 only
```

Try using python-3.10.6 
[See here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version)

Comment: I have already done that.. It's given in 1st line of the question

Comment: Sorry my bad.. 

Comment: Heroku only supports certain versions, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version

Comment: Dont know how you get python-3.6.13 installed tho.

Comment: The file was saved as runtime.txt.txt that's why it was not working. I also updated the version with 3.10.6 in the file. It's working fine now